# Display Row Number in Visible Gridview Rows

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

How can I display the row number of the visible rows in gridview? I have this code (below) but it's not working.

```
Protected Sub grd_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles grd.DataBound
        Dim iNum As Integer = 0
        For Each row As GridViewRow In grd.Rows
            Dim lblNum As Label = TryCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("lblNum"), Label)
            Dim txtRemark As TextBox = TryCast(row.Cells(10).FindControl("txtRemark"), TextBox)
            If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                        If txtRemark.Text = "F" Then
                            row.Visible = False
                        ElseIf txtRemark = "P" Then
                            row.Visible = False
                        End If
            End If
            If row.Visible = True Then
                iNum += 1
                lblNum.Text = iNum
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

[image: The image shows the right numeration in rowindex 0]

[image: The rowindex 0 should display 1 instead of 5]

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: no.. but it doesn't display the row count if i put it inside the If row.visible condition. When I remove the If condition, it displays but the numeration is incorrect.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you need. Do you just want number off the visible rows? Can you post your HTML?

Comment: is `"lblNum"` part of an asp template?

Comment: @Cory i added screenshot of my gridview

Comment: Need to see the HTML, specifically, how you are assigning 'lblNum'. If that is the asp template name. if you are not using a template, the issue might be just to change `lblNum` to `lblName`

Comment: it's an item in template..

Comment: Out of curiosity, your If statements are  hiding rows with both F and P (assuming Pass or Fail). Are you trying to display the ones that are "F"?

Comment: @Cory http://pastie.org/9505715 you can see here the whole databound code.. it depends on ddloption value.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Protected Sub grd_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles grd.DataBound
    Dim iNum As Integer = 0
    For Each row As GridViewRow In grd.Rows     
        Dim txtRemark As TextBox = TryCast(row.Cells(10).FindControl("txtRemark"), TextBox)
        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            If txtRemark.Text = "F" Then
                row.Visible = False
            ElseIf txtRemark.Text = "P" Then
                row.Visible = False
            Else
                iNum += 1
                TryCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("lblNum"), Label).Text = iNum
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```